# Similar program to rsync but to instead use a shared cache directory or source?

Tags: rsync, synchronization

With rsync, the files or data delta (difference) is compared directly between the source and destination.

Is there an alternative program that can compare the delta between the source, destination and a shared local "cache"? Where `source`
is far away and slow, while `destination` and `local-shared-cache` is local and fast.

For example if we have this state:

```
source:
largeFile.txt
largeFile2.txt
largeFile3.txt

destination:
largeFile.txt

local-shared-cache:
largeFile3.txt
```

Ignoring paths and just focusing on files, when doing a 'sync' between `source` and `destination`, the delta is 2 files of: `largeFile2.txt largeFile3.txt`.

However, `largeFile3.txt` actually already exists in `local-shared-cache` hence the 'delta' from `source` becomes only `largeFile2.txt`. An implementation using this cache would only need to transfer 1 file from the likely slow `source`.

---

I think one approach might be to use the torrent protocol (each file becomes a torrent), and if it already 'exists' in the local store, then it won't have to download it. But I'd have to implement and test this solution (and I hope maybe there already exists such a software).

Another alternative also might be something like a ZFS snapshot sync.

---

**And what am I actually trying to achieve?**

Basically we have a bunch of software projects that have a lot of large data, and a developer often needs to clone down a project and all it's data for local development. Lets say a project is 10GB which takes 20 mins to download. Now if the dev need to clone a similar project, they once again have to spend the 10GB/20mins cost even though the delta/difference between the two projects might only be a fraction of that.

**Can't I just do an initial rsync, and then rsync any differences on top of that?**

Like sure you can rsync/clone project1 initially and then rsync/clone project 2 based on that, but this gets messy fast if you need to figure out which is the 'base' clone. It also would not account if there is common assets spread across multiple projects (as opposed to just two). For example what if I have 10 projects, where each one might contain some common files. Do I rysnc all 10 sequentially one by one, 'building up' all the common elements? Seems really complicated.

Continuing on from my earlier example... Lets say I have a second project with `largeFile.txt largeFile3.txt largeFile4.txt. largeFile5.txt`

I would basically already have all the files besides `largeFile4.txt. largeFile5.txt`.

So using this approach, I can do the inital rsync which gets me largeFile2.txt, largeFile3.txt, and then do another rsync on the second project which does largeFile4.txt and largeFile5.txt. But then I need to figure all how to sequentially 'build up' all the required files with rsync, and then delete all the files that aren't required. Sounds like a lot of processing and disk processing.

Comment: rsync doesn't compare files directly, it compares metadata and checksums.  So it's not clear what advantage a cache would give.  rsync is specifically designed for use when the link betweeen local and remote is slow.  zsync (or git!!) might have some advantages in your situation.

Comment: In the example I provided, rsync would transfer a delta of 2 files (from slow network), while my intended implementation would transfer a delta of 1 file only (from slow network).

Answer (score 0):

> With rsync, the files or data delta (difference) is compared directly between the source and destination.

Not necessarily. Deltas are only used when `rsync` is used across a network connection. If you use `rsync` between two directories/files that appear to be part of the local filesystem then it won't use deltas and will instead just copy out of date files in their entirety.

```
# Will use deltas
rsync -a /path/to/source/  remoteHost:/path/to/destination

# Will copy changed files in their entirety
rsync -a /path/to/source/  /network/path/for/remoteHost/destination
```

So, assuming that deltas are being used, there is usually no need to use a cache as only changed parts of a file are transmitted.

However, in the event that you are transferring a file for the first time, and you know that a significant part of it is similar to another file, you can use `--fuzzy` and `--link-dest`/`--copy-dest` to give `rsync` a helping hand

Consider a file `new` that was based on `old`. Also allow that `old` is in a directory on the destination called `oldstuff` and you want to copy `new` to `newstuff`:

```
rsync -av --copy-dest /full/path/to/oldstuff/ --fuzzy --fuzzy /path/to/file/new remoteHost:/path/to/newstuff/
```

Just remember that if the `--copy-dest` path is relative, then it's relative to the destination directory on `remoteHost`. Generally it's best to make the path for `--copy-dest` absolute, i.e. start it with `/`, or `"$PWD"` if relative to your login directory on the remote system.

Adding two more `-v` flags to the `rsync` command gives this debugging output, confirming that it would use `old` as the basis for copying `new`:

```
rsync --dry-run -aivvv --copy-dest "$PWD"/t/dst/oldstuff/ --fuzzy --fuzzy t/src/new remoteHost:t/dst/newstuff/

opening connection using: ssh remotehost rsync --server -vvvnlyyogDtpre.iLsfxC "--log-format=%i" --copy-dest /home/roaima/t/dst/oldstuff/ . t/dst/newstuff/  (10 args)
sending incremental file list
[sender] make_file(new,*,0)
send_file_list done
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=11407
recv_file_name(new)
received 1 names
recv_file_list done
get_local_name count=1 t/dst/newstuff/
generator starting pid=11407
delta-transmission enabled
recv_generator(new,1)
[generator] make_file(/home/roaima/t/dst/oldstuff/old,*,1)
fuzzy basis selected for new: /home/roaima/t/dst/oldstuff/old
send_files(1, t/src/new)
<f+++++++++ new
generate_files phase=1
send_files phase=1
recv_files(1) starting
recv_files(new)
recv_files phase=1
generate_files phase=2
send_files phase=2
send files finished
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0
recv_files phase=2
recv_files finished
generate_files phase=3
generate_files finished

sent 65 bytes  received 515 bytes  386.67 bytes/sec
total size is 2,147,483,648  speedup is 3,702,558.01 (DRY RUN)
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1207): about to call exit(0) (DRY RUN)
```

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood your answer I don't see how this is a solution? I'm not worried about changes to file contents, when I said deltas I meant the actual files that do not exist. 

The `--fuzzy` would work if there are similar files between source and destination. But it does not account for when a file might exist in yet another possible directory (`local-shared-cache`) that is not directly in the destination directory.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I now see you've edited (and clarified) your question somewhat since I started writing the answer. Your deltas aren't really deltas in the sense of rsync at all, but the presence of new files. In that case the detail in the second part of the answer will be what you're looking for

Comment: Okay yes it seems like I'm using the word delta here incorrectly or the wrong context. I'll investigate the `--copy-dest` parameter, it does sound likely to be the solution here! Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski you'll need to consider the double `--fuzzy --fuzzy` too, unless file names in the cache match those of the target